# Linq to xml query returns no results

Tags: linq-to-xml, linqpad

I have the following xml data:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <root>
    <object name="Object01" table="Table01" pk="Table01_Id">
      <table name="Table02" pk="Table02_Id" fk="Table01_Id" include="false">
        <table name="Table03" pk="Table03_Id" fk="Table02_Id" include="true">
          <table name="Table04" pk="Table04_Id" fk="Table03_Id" include="true">
          </table>
        </table>
      </table>
      <table name="Table05" pk="Table05_Id" fk="Table01_Id" include="false">
      <table name="Table06" pk="Table06_Id" fk="Table05_Id" include="true" />
      </table>
    </object>
    <object name="Object02" table="Table07" pk="Table07_Id">
      <table name="Table08" pk="Table08_Id" fk="Table07_Id" include="false">
        <table name="Table04" pk="Table04_Id" fk="Table08_Id" include="true" />
      </table>    
    </object>
  </root>
```

When I run the following in LinqPad:

```cs
    var root = XElement.Load("D:\\Foxpert\\FlagChanges\\FlagChanges\\Modified.xml");
    var table = root.Descendants("table").Where(e => e.Attribute("name").Value == "Table04")
    .Select(e => new XElement(e.Parent)).First();
table.Dump();
     var obj = root.Descendants("object").Where(o => o.Attribute("name").Value == "Object01")
    .Select(o => new XElement(o)).First();
     obj.Dump();
     foreach (XElement t in obj.Descendants("table")){
    t.Attribute("name").Dump();
    t.Parent.Attribute("name").Dump();
}
     table.Attribute("name").Dump();
     var parent = obj.Descendants("table")
    .Where(e => e.Attribute("name")==table.Attribute("name"))
    .Select(e => new XElement(e.Parent));
     parent.Dump();
```

The parent result is empty.

Can someone try the code in LinqPad and tell me why my parent is empty?

Answer (score 1):

```
 var parent = obj.Descendants("table")
.Where(e => e.Attribute("name").Value==table.Attribute("name").Value)
.Select(e => new XElement(e.Parent));
```

`e.Attribute("name")` and `table.Attribute("name")` aren't "Equal" -- they just have the same value.